# How to apply pagination to the result of a SQL query with Joins?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I have SQL query which joins 3 tables, one being just a many-to-many connecting the other two. I use a Spring JDBC ResultSetExtractor to convert the ResultSet into my Objects which look roughly like this:

```
class Customer {
    private String id;
    private Set<AccountType> accountTypes;
    ...
}
```

The ResultSetExtractor implementation looks like this:

```
public List<Client> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException,
    DataAccessException {
        Map<Integer, Client> clientsMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Client>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            int id = rs.getInt("id");
            // add the client to the map only the first time
            if (!clientsMap.containsKey(id)) {
                Client client = new Client();
                client.setId(id);
                ...
                clientsMap.put(id, client);
            }
            // always add the account type to the existing client
            Client client = clientsMap.get(id);
            client.addAccountType(extractAccountTypeFrom(rs, id));
        }
        return new ArrayList<Client>(clientsMap.values());
}
```

This works fine without pagination.

However, I need to paginate these results. The way I usually do it is by adding this to the query, for example:

```
SELECT ... ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 30;
```

However, as this query has joins, when I limit the number of results, I am actually limiting the number of JOINED results (ie. as a client will appear as many times as the number of account types they have, the LIMIT is applied not the number of clients, but to the number of clients*accountTypes, which is not what I want).

The only solution I came up with was to remove the LIMIT (and OFFSET because that would also be wrong) from the query and apply them programmatically:

```
List<Client> allClients = jdbcTemplate.query....
List<Client> result = allClients.subList(offset, offset+limit);
```

But this is clearly not a very nice, efficient solution. Is there a better way?

Comment: Renato, How about creating a VIEW on the three table join and then using the ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 30; technique on a select * from VIEW_NAME? Run this by your DBA to see if they are happy to allow this.

Comment: @Rob Kielty - Thanks for your suggestion... I will try that to see if may be more efficient than my own solution I've just posted.

Comment: testing is the way to go. If you have a DBA maintaining the db they should be  delighted that you asked them for advice on pros and cons of each approach.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's funny how writing a question makes you think, and actually helps a lot in imagining a solution for your own problem.

I was able to solve this problem by simply adding the pagination part of the query to a sub-query of my main query, rather than to the main query itself.

For example, instead of doing:

```
SELECT client.id, client.name ...
FROM clients AS client
LEFT JOIN client_account_types AS cat ON client.id = cat.client_id
FULL JOIN account_types AS at ON cat.account_type_id = at.id
ORDER BY client.name ASC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 30;
```

I am doing this:

```
SELECT client.id, client.name ...
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM clients
    ORDER BY name ASC
    LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
) AS client
LEFT JOIN client_account_types AS cat ON client.id = cat.client_id
FULL JOIN account_types AS at ON cat.account_type_id = at.id;
```

Hope this helps other people too.

Comment: I am grappling with the same question and have not been able to figure out how this query solves the problem. If the client asked for a pageSize of 10 then it is expecting that it gets 10 clients where each client has N number of account_types and the like. So at best what you can achieve is 10 or less than 10 rows (if any client has more than one account_type) you will end up returning less than 10 rows.

Answer (score 0):

If your DBMS supports it, use the window function [DENSE_RANK](http://oncodesign.io/2017/04/22/paging-one-to-many-results-in-sql/). For example:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY name, id) count FROM 
     (SELECT a.id, a.name, b.title, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY a.name, a.id) offset_ 
      FROM AUTHOR a, BOOK b 
      WHERE a.id = b.authorId) result_offset 
   WHERE offset_ > 30) result_offset_count 
WHERE count <= 10
```