# One-to-Many for multiple tables SQL SELECT into single row

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a scenario where 3 tables.
Table1 has one to many relationship with Table2.
Table2 has one to many relationship with table3.
And in where clause I use **Description_key = UYTR**
So I want to get resultset in one row. is there any way? can some one suggest me please?

```
Table1
Id District Description_key
1  ABC      UYTR
2  DEF      UYTR
3  GHI      UYTR
4  IJK      UYTR
```

```
Table2
Id Taluk Table1_ID_FK
1  UUU   1
2  III   1
3  OOO   1
4  PPP   2
5  TTT   2
6  QQQ   3
```

```
Table3
ID  Hobli  Table2_ID_FK
1   Bhuh   1
2   tyty   1
3   tyty   1
4   PPPP   2
5   JHGF   2
```

Comment: Please show us the results that you want. Also, what have you tried so far, where did you get stuck?

Comment: I dont know how to achieve for 3 tables. But I want to see the output one line. table1.id | table1.District | table2.taluk| table3.id | table3.hobli |

Answer (score 1):

Do you want a simple `JOIN` on the foreign keys?

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9be0442551f91e94f634b4e544886d24)

```
SELECT
    *
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Table1_ID_FK
JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.Id = t3.Table2_ID_FK
```

Simple `JOIN` removes records, if no related JOIN records exist:

```
Id | District | Description_key | Id | Taluk | Table1_ID_FK | ID | Hobli | Table2_ID_FK
-: | :------- | :-------------- | -: | :---- | -----------: | -: | :---- | -----------:
1 | ABC      | UYTR            |  1 | UUU   |            1 |  1 | Bhuh  |            1
1 | ABC      | UYTR            |  1 | UUU   |            1 |  2 | tyty  |            1
1 | ABC      | UYTR            |  1 | UUU   |            1 |  3 | tyty  |            1
1 | ABC      | UYTR            |  2 | III   |            1 |  4 | PPPP  |            2
1 | ABC      | UYTR            |  2 | III   |            1 |  5 | JHGF  |            2
```

`LEFT JOIN` keeps the other records:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Table1_ID_FK
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.Id = t3.Table2_ID_FK
```

Result:

```
Id | District | Description_key |   Id | Taluk | Table1_ID_FK |   ID | Hobli | Table2_ID_FK
-: | :------- | :-------------- | ---: | :---- | -----------: | ---: | :---- | -----------:
 1 | ABC      | UYTR            |    1 | UUU   |            1 |    1 | Bhuh  |            1
 1 | ABC      | UYTR            |    1 | UUU   |            1 |    2 | tyty  |            1
 1 | ABC      | UYTR            |    1 | UUU   |            1 |    3 | tyty  |            1
 1 | ABC      | UYTR            |    2 | III   |            1 |    4 | PPPP  |            2
 1 | ABC      | UYTR            |    2 | III   |            1 |    5 | JHGF  |            2
 1 | ABC      | UYTR            |    3 | OOO   |            1 |  null|  null |         null
 2 | DEF      | UYTR            |    4 | PPP   |            2 |  null|  null |         null
 2 | DEF      | UYTR            |    5 | TTT   |            2 |  null|  null |         null
 3 | GHI      | UYTR            |    6 | QQQ   |            3 |  null|  null |         null
 4 | IJK      | UYTR            |  null| null  |          null|  null|  null |         null
```

Comment: Could you show me how the result looks for this?  Suppose if the table1 has 3(id1, id2, id3) record and table2 has 4(t21, t22,t23,t24) records (3 for id1 and 1 for id2) and table3 has 3 records. Table3 records belongs to t21 . How the result looks like

Comment: I added the outputs and a fiddle, where you can test it. If it does not fit your examples, please add the real examples, and the expected output (as I did here in the answer) to the question! Maybe you can modify the fiddle to fit what you want

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973365/how-to-apply-pagination-to-the-result-of-a-sql-query-with-joins this helped me. Thank you.